# Search box in Access multi field search form not working

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, search

I have created a multi field search form for two tables, "SONGS" and "INSTRUMENTALISTS". They have a one-to-many relationship, with the primary key field "Song Title" in the "SONGS" table being connected to the foreign key field "Song Title" in the "INSTRUMENTALISTS" table.
For my query, I have made it so it brings up all the fields in both tables, except for the foreign key field when I search for something.

I have the following fields in the "SONGS" table: Song Title, Artist, Album, Composer, Conductor, Arranger, Record Label, Year Recorded, Format, Length of Track, and Live or Studio. In the multi field search form, all of the search boxes for these fields work fine and bring up the correct entries in the query.
In the "INSTRUMENTALISTS" table, I have a Song Title field to connect the tables by, and 10 Instrumentalist fields, labeled Instrumentalist 1, Instrumentalist 2, Instrumentalist 3, and so on.

When I search for an entry using the Instrumentalist box of the search form, the query comes up as blank, even if there is text in all the fields of the rows in the "INSTRUMENTALISTS" table. If I search for an entry using any of the other boxes in the search form, everything works fine. All the other search boxes search through their respective columns (Song title search box searches in the "song title" column, etc).

With the Instrumentalist search box, I want to be able to search through all of the fields in the INSTRUMENTALISTS table labeled Instrumentalist 1, Instrumentalist 2, Instrumentalist 3, etc, all the way through Instrumentalist 10. I would also like it so I can only search for part of the entry, for example, if I want to search for everyone with the name James, or anyone with an A in their name, I can do that and don't have to search for a specific whole entry, such as "James Brown". That's why I used the code below.

In my query, for the criteria in these Instrumentalist 1-10 fields, my code is `Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![Instrumentalist] & "*"`.

Here is my "SONGS" table, along with the corresponding entries from the "INSTRUMENTALISTS" table underneath each "SONGS" table entry. [My tables...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg5io.png)

Here is my search form. The box circled in red is the one giving me trouble. [Search form...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcvUG.png)

If anyone could help me figure out what the problem is with the Instrumentalist search box and why it doesn't make any query results pop up, that would be great. Let me know if you would like me to give you a link to the Access file.

Comment: Your design for your INSTRUMENTALIST table is wrong. You should store each and every instrumentalist in a separate ROW (record). Having said that, post the SQL of your query.

Comment: @Rene I don't understand why my INSTRUMENTALIST table would be wrong/not working when I have formatted my SONGS table the same way and the SONGS part works fine. It says my SQL is too long to post as a comment so here is a download link to the whole file. I had to switch a couple things up in the SONGS table regarding categories as well as in the INSTRUMENTALIST table (per request of the person I am making this for) but the SONGS table still works fine. [Music Library Database Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B84WlZVCOUxxVXpSaHJrcXlLSkU)

Comment: Read up on normalization. Once more, in database land you store each and every instance in a separate row. Hence in your case, each and every instrumentalist should be stored in a single row. Are you able to generate an Access file in 2007 format as I only have access to an 2007 environment (yeah I know, bit outdated). PS add your SQL to your original question, not as a comment. Having said that, your SQL is pretty basic (hence rather short) if your database would be properly normalized. So once more, do read up on normalization before you create a "pain in the ass" Acess application ;)